# If $f$ is injective, demonstrate that $f \circ g = f \circ h \implies g = h$

Tags: functions

I'm trying to do this exercise:

> With functions:
>
> $$f : A \rightarrow B$$
>
> $$g : C \rightarrow A$$
>
> $$h : C \rightarrow A$$
>
> Demonstrate that if $f$ is injective, then $f \circ g = f \circ h \implies g = h$

So we have two premises:

- $f$ is injective
- $f\circ g = f\circ h$

$f$ being injective means that $(\forall a,b \in A)(f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b)$. Different elements in $A$ map to different elements in $B$.

I am not sure what can I infer from the fact that $f\circ g = f\circ h$.

The composition $f\circ h$ goes something like $C \rightarrow A \rightarrow B$. Since $f$ is injective and it was used to form the composition, can I say that $f\circ h$ is also injective? Well, even so I am not sure what would I do next.

---

Although I'm presenting this exercise, the real problem is that I don't quite get how to use function properties (injective or surjective) to deduce what happens to such function when it acts in an operation (in this case $\circ$) with another function. Is the result still injective? It depends? Etc. It would be great to get more feedback on that.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481811/prove-that-f-is-one-to-one-iff-f-circ-h-f-circ-k-implies-h-k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is injective then
$$f(g(x))=f(h(x))\implies g(x)=h(x)$$
for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contradiction: $g\neq h\implies g(x)\neq h(x)$ for some $x\in C$ $\implies f\circ g(x)\neq f\circ h(x) \implies f\circ g\neq f\circ h$

Comment: Wait, what is the contradiction? Plus, in what part did you apply the fact that $f$ is injective?

Comment: Because $g\neq h \implies f\circ g\neq f\circ h$, $f\circ g \neq f\circ h\implies g\neq h$. I used the fact that $f$ is injective when $g(x)\neq h(x) \implies f(g(x))\neq f(h(x))$